# Android emulator in visual studio not launching even though Hyper-V is installed and enabled

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, hyper-v

I am attempting to run android emulator through Visual Studio 2019 to test an app I am creating with Xamarin. I followed the steps to enable and install Hyper-V as outlined in the documentation: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows)

When I try to launch my emulated device I get this message:

```html
Starting emulator pixel_3_pie_9_0_api_28 ...
1>Waiting for runtime checks to complete
Emulator pixel_3_pie_9_0_api_28 cannot be started.
Runtime checks completed
1>Starting deployment to pixel_3_pie_9_0_api_28 ...
1>Starting emulator pixel_3_pie_9_0_api_28 ...
1>Launching the Android Emulator pixel_3_pie_9_0_api_28 on Hyper-V needs the Windows Hypervisor Platform installed and enabled.
1>
1>Please configure it using the Turn Windows features on or off dialog.
1>
Build has been canceled.
```

I am not sure why this is happening as I have Hyper-V installed and enabled. Any ideas would be wonderful!

Relevant Images:
[Windows Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtr9I.png)
[CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Msc.png)

Comment: If answer be helpful , remember to mark ot vote up later when have time.Thanks in advance *.^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If have changed **Windows Hypervisor Platform** option ,

[image]

Then you need to **restart computer** , then it can work.

[image]

Last when creating device , select a processor type for this virtual device by clicking the **Processor** pull-down menu. Selecting **x86** will provide the best performance because it enables the emulator to take advantage of [hardware acceleration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows).

[image]